# Can you remove the dropdown arrow in the navigation bar using flatsome theme for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web, drop-down-menu

I have tried to remove the dropdown arrow that appears when making a dropdown menu in wordpress.I have not found a solution so I was wondering you can type in any extra css to fix it.

Thanks!

Arrow is next to "hudvård" in the menu.

Picture: [drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9dYI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown arrow is a Font Awesome icon `<i class="icon-angle-down"></i>`.

You can use `.nav-top-link i { display:none; }` to hide it with CSS.